# How to tell Hibernate's 2nd Level Cache to use the proper Id?

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa, ehcache-3

In a Spring Boot 3 application using Hibernate 6 and Ehcache 3 I ran into a weird problem. My entities have an `id` property which property-name is prefixed by the entity name, so for example a Display entity would have an `id` named `displayId`.

The entity with cache annotation looks like that:

```java
@Entity
@Access(AccessType.FIELD)
@org.hibernate.annotations.Cache(region = "display-cache",
                                 usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
@Table(name = "display")
public class Display {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "display_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long displayId;

    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;

    //...
}
```

Now, as long as I query for a display using the built-in `findById()` method of the `JpaRepository` everything is fine and the display gets cached as expected. But when I try to query for the id-property field `displayId` itself there is no caching, although the parameter is the `id` of the entity:

The `JpaRepository` looks like this:

```java
public interface DisplayRepository extends JpaRepository<Display, Long> {

    Optional<Display> findByDisplayId(Long displayId);

}
```

And the query looks like that:

```java
displayRepository.findByDisplayId(id);  // cache is not working

// just for comparison:
displayRepository.findById(id);         // cache is working
```

So my question is:

How can I tell Hibernate that the used displayId is the id of the entity so that Hibernate will do the caching as expected?

Comment: your question is actually answered there: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74884096/3426309

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64190242/in-spring-data-jpa-a-derived-find-method-doesnt-use-first-level-cache-while-ca/64193546

Comment: @ AndreyB.Panfilov, @ crizzis: Many thanks for the links, they actually helped a lot to gain a better understanding. To sum that up: every db call which is not done via `entityManager.find()` cannot be cached classically, neither 1st nor 2nd level cache. So they all count as some kind of *query-calls* and have either be processed up to the db or be backed up by a query cache. All derived JPA query methods as well as all custom JPA methods even using the `@id` annotated *primary key* are treated as custom query calls.

Comment: Hibernate only hooks into `findById()` JPA repo-methods. That's how HBN works, and there is no way to help HBN via *annotations*. If I'm seeing that right I now at least know what can be done how to deal with it. If I'm wrong, please let me know. Once again: thank you both for your help and insights.

Comment: @Slevin, yes, correct, however, that is not a HBN "issue" - that is how `spring-data-jpa` was implemented.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that, HBN follows JPA, Ehcache follows JCache, and I follow wife ;). Anyhow, the important thing is that I now know how to handle the cache properly. Although it seems a bit obvious after reading all question/answer/comments here, it might be a good thing for others to have this kind of information summed up in a short answer/explanation since I haven't found it somewhere else (maybe this will become 2nd nature in a few years, but for beginners these kind of information is brutal necessary). I'll surely would appreciate that coming from an experienced developer. Many thanks

Comment: @AndreyB.Panfilov : Or maybe, if this would be ok with you, you could confirm the summary VonC did, putting all information together (thats good effort too), and if his summary is correct (which seems to me) I can also take that for accepted. However, you all helped a lot, many thanks again.

Comment: it will take some time to write thorough explanation.

Comment: It's totally up to you, I won't bother you since I am the one yet knowing all these things for now (until I will forget them again...) But as a former seeker I can confirm that there are many Hibernate/Ehcache beginners who are struggling really hard at the moment, especially in combination with Spring Boot 3. However, I can wait having cookies and coffee in the meantime...

Comment: @Slevin A small correction to: 'every db call which is not done via entityManager.find() cannot be cached classically, neither 1st nor 2nd level cache' - this is only true until **query cache** is not enabled. Perhaps that's what you're looking for

Comment: Thanks @crizzis for this correction. What I meant with *classically* was caching without relying on *query-caches* which I use as well but explicitly for special service methods (and which has to be backed up by a classic entity cache [and thus that combination is for my understanding bit slower]). But for the majority of *normal* caching I want to rely on Hibernates magic as much as possible using the simple entity cache.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Implementing 2nd-level cache in Hibernate is not so straightforward as you might read in someone's blogposts, and the rule of thumb is following: if you are able to implement caching on service/business level - do that without looking back and stay clear of 2nd-level cache.

Below are some my thoughts based on my previous researches:

**I**. The implementation is buggy and no one is going to fix that: [2nd-level cache does not work as expected](https://discourse.hibernate.org/t/2nd-level-cache-does-not-work-as-expected/7041), that worth to note I have discovered those issues using integration tests only, so, I have no idea why this functionality is not covered by tests in Hibernate project.

**II**. You need to think about how are you going to deal with stale data in cache: you may both override actual data with the stale one or make wrong decisions based on stale data, both situations do not look good. The most straightforward way is to enable version stamp checks via `@Version` fields, however, "version checking" is completely another universe and you may face with challenges you have never faced with before (on the other hand I can't understand how someone uses JPA without version checking)

**III**. Do not use spring caching capabilities together with JPA repositories: spring is not designed for caching mutable data, JPA entities are mutable by design, instead of performance improvements you will get wrong data in DB.

**IV**. If application modifies entities via `update` (`@Modifying` and `@Query(update/delete)` in JPA repositories), those operations invalidate caches  - avoid using such patterns

**V**. Query caching does not work at all due to following reasons:

1. If you are retrieving entities, HBN caches corresponding identifiers, successive cache hits will retrieve entities using those cached ids one-by-one, slow-by-slow
2. modifying entities from the same query space (i.e. entities backed by the same tables as tables involved in the query to be cached) invalidates query cache - HBN is unable to figure out whether the entity to be updated/deleted affects query result or not, so it invalidates everything.

**VI**. global/distributed caches seem to be useless, local caches accepting remote invalidation messages seem to be OK: the problem is if entity does not have "a lot of" associations retrieving it from DB via single query should not be slower than retrieving it from remote cache, so, from user experience perspective global/distributed cache does improve nothing.

**VII**. I do believe the idea of controlling cache behaviour via annotations over entity classes is completely wrong, the point is following: entities just define data, however assumptions about possible optimisations and data consistency is a responsibility of particular application, so, in my opinion the best option to setup caching is to take advantage of `org.hibernate.integrator.spi.Integrator`, for example:

```java
@Override
public void integrate(Metadata metadata, SessionFactoryImplementor sessionFactory, SessionFactoryServiceRegistry serviceRegistry) {
    for (PersistentClass persistentClass : metadata.getEntityBindings()) {
        if (persistentClass instanceof RootClass) {
            RootClass rootClass = (RootClass) persistentClass;
            if ("myentity".equals(rootClass.getEntityName())) {
                rootClass.setCached(true);
                rootClass.setCacheRegionName("myregion");
                rootClass.setCacheConcurrencyStrategy(AccessType.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE.getExternalName());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**VIII** The safest way of implementing 2nd-level cache in Hibernate is following:

1. at first, let HBN to feed up 2nd-level cache:

```java
@Bean
public HibernatePropertiesCustomizer hibernateSecondLevelCacheCustomizer() {
    return map -> {
        map.put(AvailableSettings.JPA_SHARED_CACHE_RETRIEVE_MODE, CacheRetrieveMode.BYPASS);
        map.put(AvailableSettings.JPA_SHARED_CACHE_STORE_MODE, CacheStoreMode.USE);
    };
}
```

2. after that you may call `EntityManager#find(Class<T>, Object, Map<?,?>)` method with `AvailableSettings#JAKARTA_JPA_SHARED_CACHE_RETRIEVE_MODE` property set to `CacheRetrieveMode#USE` if you think it is appropriate

---

As regards to your problem...

There are a couple of options to retrieve entity by id in Hibernate:

1. `EntityManager#find` - the most common one, does respect both 2nd- and 1st-level caches
2. `EntityManager#getReference` - instead of retrieving an entity, it creates proxy object, there are some scenarios when it could be useful, however HBN implementation seems to be broken: successive call of `EntityManager#find` returns proxy object instead of full-functional entity
3. `Session#byMultipleIds` - allows to retrieve entities of the same type in batches, does respect both 2nd- and 1st-level caches, unfortunately, is not supported by JPA repositories
4. via JPQL query like `select e from entity e where e.id=:id` - the most bizarre option to do the simple thing:

   - when auto flush is enabled (which is actually a reasonable default for the most Hibernate applications), Hibernate tends to keep DB state in sync with persistence context, which in turn means that before executing any JPQL query Hibernate will check whether persistence context contains dirty entities (that takes some time) and flush those dirty entities into DB.
   - if entity to be retrieved is already present in persistent context, Hibernate won't refresh its state using DB data, such behaviour seems to be weird

From JPA repository perspective every declared method, which is not `default` and is not implemented by base repository ([`SimpleJpaRepository` in the most cases](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-jpa/reference/repositories/custom-implementations.html#repositories.customize-base-repository)) or [`fragment`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-jpa/reference/repositories/custom-implementations.html#repositories.single-repository-behavior), is backed up by JPQL query and, thus, may not work as intended/desired in some corner cases.

so, the best option for particular case is to give up on using naming convention which causes performance issues, if that is not possible you may take advantage of using `default` methods:

```java
default Optional<Display> findByDisplayId(Long displayId) {
   return findById(displayId);
}
```

Comment: Great insights and a great summary. Many valuable things to take away. I'd wish there would be much more information of that kind to find, reflecting daily work with tricky software. Thus thanks for this really helpful article.

Answer (score 1):

When querying by `displayId` with `findByDisplayId(id)`, the cache does not seem to recognize `displayId` as the identifier of the entity and does not operate as expected, unlike when using `findById(id)` which works fine.

A possible solution would be to use [Hibernate's `@NaturalId` annotation](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-hibernate-natural-ids), also [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1910220/6309).
A natural ID is an immutable business key which is unique within the scope of a particular database table. In your case, the `displayId` is acting as this business key.
But since `displayId` is *already* annotated with `@Id`, indicating it as the primary key for the entity: overloading the identity concept with a natural ID on the same field could lead to confusion and unexpected behavior.

Another possibility: Creating a custom query method that leverages [Hibernate's 2nd Level Cache](https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-second-level-cache) explicitly, using [`@Query` annotation](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-query) with the `@Cacheable` annotation to make sure caching is utilized (illustrated in "[Caching in Hibernate](https://medium.com/@himani.prasad016/caching-in-hibernate-3ad4f479fcc0)" by [Himani Prasad](https://twitter.com/himaniprasad8)).

However:

> The second approach is the classic query-cache approach I use for some special cases. I could do a workaround this way, but that would mean to have two caches, while the query cache is for what I know a bit slower than a dedicated entity cache alone.

Using [`@EntityGraph` annotation](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-named-entity-graphs#graph-definition) to hint Hibernate to fetch the entity in a cache-friendly manner, even when combining with [`QueryHints`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/support/QueryHints.html). `@QueryHints` is mentioned in "[11 JPA and Hibernate query hints every developer should know](https://thorben-janssen.com/11-jpa-hibernate-query-hints-every-developer-know/)" by [Thorben Janssen](https://twitter.com/thjanssen123).

But does not work here. The goal would be to ensure that Hibernate's 2nd Level Cache is utilized when querying by `displayId`, without resorting to the query cache.

[Andrey B. Panfilov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3426309/andrey-b-panfilov) suggests in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77413640/how-to-tell-hibernates-2nd-level-cache-to-use-the-proper-id/77425506?noredirect=1#comment136497174_77425506)

> `default Optional<Display> findByDisplayId(Long displayId) {return findById(displayId);}`.
>
> When HBN is caching queries it caches ids only, so, despite any hints you have provided it will always call `em.find()`, moreover, such "caches" get invalidated upon any entity of corresponding type gets saved, thus such caches are completely useless.

That would indeed be a straightforward method to utilize Hibernate's 2nd Level Cache by delegating the `findByDisplayId` method to the built-in [`findById` method](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.html#findById(ID)) of the `JpaRepository`. That makes sure the `em.find()` method, which is cache-aware, is utilized when querying by `displayId`.

```java
public interface DisplayRepository extends JpaRepository<Display, Long> {

    default Optional<Display> findByDisplayId(Long displayId) {
        return findById(displayId);
    }

}
```

When caching queries, Hibernate caches entity identifiers only, not the entities themselves. And the cache gets invalidated whenever any entity of the corresponding type gets saved.

Andrey detailed that approach in "[JPA Query with several different @Id columns](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74884096/6309)", with:

```java
default Optional<T> findByIdAndType(K id, String type) {
    return findById(id)
            .filter(e -> Objects.equals(e.getType(), type));
}
```

The `EntityManager#find` method would be the most efficient way to retrieve entities by ID: it backs up the `CrudRepository#findById` method in Spring Data JPA, which is designed to utilize Hibernate's 2nd Level Cache effectively.

From [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77413640/how-to-tell-hibernates-2nd-level-cache-to-use-the-proper-id?noredirect=1#comment136501831_77413640): Any database call that is not made via `entityManager.find()` is not automatically cached by Hibernate's 1st or 2nd level cache and is treated as a custom query call.
These include derived JPA query methods and custom JPA methods, even when they use the `@Id` annotated primary key.

Hibernate's caching mechanism is directly tied to the `findById()` method in JPA repositories, and this is not an "issue" with Hibernate but rather the way `spring-data-jpa` is designed.

While annotations cannot directly influence Hibernate to treat custom query methods as cacheable `find` operations, using a default method that delegates to `findById()` within your repository interface is an idiomatic way to achieve the desired caching behavior with Hibernate and Spring Data JPA.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation. I know about the possibility of `@NaturalId` and I use it in some entities to help Hibernate's 1st level cache with equals(). But as you mentioned, I also think it's not the go-to strategy for this explicit problem (however, I'll keep it in mind). The second approach is the classic query-cache approach I use for some special cases. I could do a workaround this way, but that would mean to have two caches, while the query cache is for what I know a bit slower than a dedicated entity cache alone. Anyhow, thanks at the moment you for your insights.

Comment: @Slevin Good point (on using a "dedicated entity cache alone"). I have edited the answer to address your comment.

Comment: @Slevin next time you when your customer will loose data and ask you why that did happen, you will have a "good" excuse for that: someone on SO with outstanding reputation have suggested me to do that. You was suggested to inject backdoor into your code, so, the suggestion were downvoted by myself.

Comment: @AndreyB.Panfilov Would the `@EntityGraph`+`QueryHints` that I mentioned in the edited answer be also dangerous?

Comment: @AndreyB.Panfilov I'm sorry I haven't seen that backdoor code. If there was one, thank you for pointing this out and as it seems to have it removed from the answer. VonC `@EntityGraph(attributePaths = { "displayId" })` doesn't seem to do the trick, the entity is not getting cached. Adding `@QueryHints` will activate the query cache, but that I want to avoid somehow and instead tell Hibernate to cache properly (the EntityGraph approach would be nice if it worked, but unfortunately it doesn't) - or maybe I'm just missing something?

Comment: @Slevin OK, so the goal would be to ensure that Hibernate's 2nd Level Cache is utilized when querying by `displayId`, without resorting to the query cache?

Comment: @VonC Yep, that's what I want to achieve. Using Hibernate's classic caching approach through the entity's `id`.

Comment: @VonC The only suggestion TC actually needs is: `default Optional<Display> findByDisplayId(Long displayId) {return findById(displayId);}`. When HBN is caching queries it caches ids only, so, despite on any hints you have provided it will always call `em.find()`, moreover, such "caches" get invalidated upon any entity of corresponding type gets saved, thus such caches are completely useless.

Comment: @AndreyB.Panfilov Good point. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility, let me know if I have misconstrued your feedback.

Comment: @Slevin OK, I have edited the answer to reflect your feedbacks.