# Spring Data JPA: Hibernate Query Cache is invalidated even if unrelated records are added, modified or deleted

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, query-cache, hibernate-cache

Hibernate Query Cache is getting invalidated even if unrelated record is added, deleted or modified.

**Entity**

```
@Entity
@Cache(region = "book", usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
public class Book {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;

  private String name;

  public String category;
}
```

**Repository**

```
@Repository
public interface BookRepository extends CrudRepository<Book, Long> {
  @QueryHints({@QueryHint(name = org.hibernate.jpa.QueryHints.HINT_CACHEABLE, value = "true")})
  Iterable<Book> findAllByCategory(String category);
}
```

**Testing**

If I fetch book by one category (`Novel`), data is returned from cache from second call. But when I add/modify/delete any record for other category, previous query cache is invalidated.

**Expectation**

I am expecting that a query cache should be invalidated only if record matching bind parameter are added/deleted/modified.

**Update 1**

On further testing, I observed that cache is invalidated if there change in any table (Even the tables for which Query Cache is not enabled)

Comment: That is actually expected HBN behaviour (which in turn makes query caching useless: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77430916/3426309) - in general it is not possible to say whether entity modification affects cached data or not, imagine your repository method is `findAllByCategoryIngoreCase(String category)`, how HBN should handle that?

Comment: @AndreyB.Panfilov thanks for comment. On further testing, I observed that cache is invalidated if there change in any table (Even the tables for which Query Cache is not enabled). Is this the expected behaviour? I believe, invalidation should be at least localized to tables in which change is made